# IPython install from GitHub

Tags: github, ipython

I have opened an enhanced console on my C: derive and pulled IPython from GitHub.

The nice python developer at my work had to shoot off on holiday before the install completed and left one line of commands as an instruction. Unfortunately when i type them into the Enhanced Console I get an error. Command and error below:

Command:
python setupegg.py develop

Error:
"python: can't open file 'setupegg.py' : [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Did you check the path?** The command you posted assumes that there's a `setupegg.py` file in the working directory.

Comment: Just checked and there definitely is no such file...or a file with that name in any of the sub directories. Should there be?

Comment: Try `python3 setup.py install`

Comment: I think we are using python 2.73. So I type "python2.73 setup.py install"?

Comment: Also, when i try "python setup.py install" I get an error saying "no module named setupext"

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Windows 7. Am i missing some files from the GitHub download do you think?

Comment: `setupext` should be a folder in your Github checkout - check that it's there.

Comment: Incase you're unaware, Check out the  install instructions and its github [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython).

Answer (score 3):

This is generally the quickest way to install IPython from GitHub:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/ipython/ipython#egg=ipython
```

The same goes for pretty much any Python package on GitHub.

Comment: What's the difference between this and this, which I found elsewhere and used: `pip install -e git+https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git#egg=ipython`